# How to build dom element from given path

Tags: javascript, html

I when scripting get a problem.
I have a path in dom element.
Example `body > div.wrapper > div#drag.draggable`
And i want transfer this path to dom element as

```
    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="drag" class="draggable"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

similar to this. Please help.

Comment: not clear what you are asking !

Comment: You will have to use a CSS parser like https://github.com/fb55/css-what and convert the JSON to HTML DOM.

Comment: check emmet plugin [Emmet](https://emmet.io/)

Comment: OP wants to have a function `createDOM("body > div.wrapper > div#drag.draggable")` which creates the DOM element structure in his example, which can then be added to the document root or another existing element. CSS-What generates JSON and I think Emmet is only suitable for editors.

Comment: @edwin Thanks. Now have a plugin or library emmet for javascript?